# Keeping the materialized value of a source passed to a chunked request entity (client-side)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

The Akka HTTP client API allows passing a `Source[ChunkStreamPart, Any]` to a `HttpEntity.Chunked`, which makes it possible to push a stream of `ByteString`s into a single HTTP request with backpressure handling:

```scala
val data: Source[ByteString, Future[ImportantInformation]]
val chunkedEntity = HttpEntity.Chunked(
    ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, 
    data.map(ChunkStreamPart(_)))
val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST,
    Uri("http://targethost/path"), entity = chunkedEntity)
val downstreamResp : Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(request)
```

Now, the source is consumed far down in the transport layer, and I can't find a way to access the `Future[ImportantInformation]` materialized value from my `Source`. Is there a way to work around this problem, i.e. either a method that would let me access the materialized value, or even some kind of `Sink` in the library that sinks a stream of `ByteString`s into a *single* HTTP request?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mapMaterializedValue`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#mapMaterializedValue[Mat2](f:Mat=>Mat2):Source.this.ReprMat[Out,Mat2]) on your source to access its materialized value.

```
val data: Source[ByteString, Future[ImportantInformation]]
val mappeddata = 
  data.mapMaterializedValue(future => processImportantInformation(future))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for one of our cases. In the other one, we ended up running the source with a `Sink.asPublisher()` and then passing a `Source.fromPublisher()` into the `RequestEntity`, thereby getting access to the materialized value, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to specify `ImportantInformation` but just want to know when the `Source` receives a termination message then you can use [`Source.watchTermination`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#watchTermination[Mat2]()(matF:(Mat,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done])=%3EMat2):FlowOpsMat.this.ReprMat[Out,Mat2]).  This will materialize a `Future[Done]`.

There is a good example [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255354/monitoring-a-closed-graph-akka-stream).

Comment: Hi Ramon, unfortunately I *do* need to get the `ImportantInformation`. I had a look at the linked example, but it seems that neither `watchTermination` nor `Sink.actorRef` (as it only accepts a static termination message) will give me access to it. Do you have any ideas on how to circumvent this?